# zero to hero NFT example cli to js workflo

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to follow the near zero to hero nft example which is described with cli commands. I it working with cli commands but struggling to convert it to javascript. In particular I am trying to simply call a view script on the nft contract which has been deployed to a subaccount. So I load the account;

```
this.nft_contract = await this._near.near.loadContract(this.nft_contract_id, {
      viewMethods: ["nft_metadata","nft_token","nft_payout","nft_is_approved","nft_tokens","nft_supply_for_owner","nft_tokens_for_owner"],
      // Change (“call”) methods can modify the state. But you don't receive the returned value when called.
      changeMethods: ["new_default_meta","new","nft_mint","nft_transfer","nft_transfer_call","nft_transfer_payout","nft_approve","nft_revoke","nft_revoke_all"],
      sender: window.walletConnection.getAccountId()
    });
```

and then call the view function nft_metadata as shown the the zero to hero example, but with js as follows;

```
await this.nft_contract.nft_metadata()
```

I get the error missing field `account_id`, which I can only assume relates to the backend rpc call. The cli example explicitly states the account_id argument, but any examples ive seen to call a contract argument dont give that option. Is is something to do with how my code logs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project should answer most questions about calling your contract from the frontend

https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-api-js

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you call the methods on contract, you also need to specify the requried parameter(s) in the method. In this case, it's `account_id`, and we need to add it as an object (even though the contract signature takes a string as an argument) for contract calls like this:

```js
// account_id can be your testnet account, e.g. johnonym.testnet
await this.nft_contract.nft_metadata({account_id: 'your-account-id'})
```

However, this method in particular shouldn't need any parameters to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't inheriting a system variable successfully so there was no account id. All seems to be working now. Thanks for the pointers that eventually lead to me finding the bug.

Comment: I'm happy you figured it out. If you can add some more explanation on how you changed the system variables, maybe this answer can be useful for others as well? And you are allowed to accept your own answer.